# Failing to set up Huawei surf-stick

Tags: usb, internet

As the title says, I am trying to set up a Huawei surf-stick (Huawei E303) on my raspberry 3B. The system is up-to-date and should be pretty clean.

I am trying to follow these guides:

https://raspberry.tips/raspberrypi-tutorials/usb-surfstick-am-raspberry-pi-verwenden-mobiles-internet

https://tutorials-raspberrypi.de/raspberry-pi-gsm-modul-mobiles-internet/

The stick is shown by `lsusb` as

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

both, with `usb-modeswitch` installed and uninstalled. However, I can't seem to get any further.

With the stick attached there is the problem that internet (via ethernet or built-in wifi) stops working. The wired symptom is that a download with `wget` (e.g. `wget 'www.google.com'`) yields an `index.html`, but the content of the file is 'crumbled' (obviously it contains some binary code instead of the plain ascii).
This will also cause `apt-get` to fail installing additional software.

Trying to proceed with the next step outlined in the first guide I am running `wvdialconf`. This gives

```
> sudo wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf
Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

Scanning your serial ports for a modem.



Sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program?
Did you configure it properly with setserial?

Please read the FAQ at http://alumnit.ca/wiki/?WvDial
```

With the stick attached, I also see the following additional network device with `ifconfig`:

```
    eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.8.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.8.255
    inet6 fe80::1de0:f84f:6b83:1f79  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:1e:10:1f:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 44  bytes 16733 (16.3 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 62  bytes 6771 (6.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note that I was able to get the same surf-stick running on a current ubuntu and its firmware seems up-to-date.

Comment: It seems that this problem was caused by the stick not getting a network connection (strange symptoms). It is probably sufficient to do `sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch`. I then did `sudo usb_modeswitch -J -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1f01` which makes the output of `lsusb` change to the above. Before that the output contains `0x1f01`. But this second step may not be necessary. The changes seem to be persistent.

Comment: feel free to answer your own question and accept it! These usb stick modems gave me such nightmares with the RPi.